# Alternative proof that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

We have a retraction $r:X\rightarrow A$ such that and $X$ is Hausdorff and we want to prove that $A$ is closed. Since $r$ is a continuous function cant we say that since this is true: $r(a)=a$ for all $a\in A$ that this is true:Then $a\in r^{-1}(A)$ and since all singletons are closed in Hausdorff spaces then $A$ is closed? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're good through the claim that $a \in r^{-1}(A)$. But note that $r^{-1}(A) = X$, so this isn't actually saying anything interesting! Everything after this in your argument is completely unjustified.

Comment: You have only used the property that singleton sets are closed in a Hausdorff space, but this property (the $T_1$ axiom) does not imply what you are trying to prove. The [line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold) is $T_1$, but the function that maps one of the origins to the other and fixes all other points is a retract with open range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative proof: suppose $A$ were not closed, and let $x \in \overline{A}\setminus A$. Then there is a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) $I \to A, (a_i)_{i \in I}$ so that $a_i \to x$. But then $r(a_i)=a_i$ for all $i$ (property of a retract) so $r(a_i) \to x$ but by continuity of $r$ we *also* have that $r(a_i)\to r(x)$. But as $r(x) \neq x$ (because $r(x) \in A$ by definiton and $x \notin A$ by assumption, this contradicts that the limit of a convergent net in a Hausdorff space is unique. Contradiction. So $A$ is closed.

Comment: That was my initial proof, thanks for taking the time to answer. Would you be willing to help with the above answer and show me the contradiction?

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, the fact that $a\in r^{-1}[A]$ says nothing that we didn’t already know: $r^{-1}[A]=X$, and $a\in A\subseteq X$, so of course $a\in X$. It is of course true that $\{a\}$ is closed in $X$, since $X$ is Hausdorff, but that says nothing about whether $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}\{a\}$ is closed in $X$: arbitrary unions of closed sets are not in general closed.

HINT: You would do better to suppose that $A$ is not closed and let $x\in\operatorname{cl}A\setminus A$. Let $a=r(x)$ then $a\in A$, so $a\ne x$. $X$ is Hausdorff, so there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$ and $a\in V$. Now use the continuity of $f$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: I dont really get it, can you maybe walk me through it so I can understand better?

Comment: @ChrisEwing: $r$ is continuous, so $r^{-1}[V]$ is open, and therefore $U\cap r^{-1}[V]$ is an open nbhd of $x$. And $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$, so every open nbhd of $x$ contains a point of $A$. Let $y\in A\cap U\cap r^{-1}[V]$; then $r(y)=y$ (why?), and $r(y)\in V$ (why?). Why is this impossible?