# Reference to proof that a retract of a Hausdorff space is closed

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

So in this [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093546/alternative-proof-that-a-retract-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-closed/4094092?r=SearchResults#4094092`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093546/alternative-proof-that-a-retract-of-a-hausdorff-space-is-closed/4094092?r=SearchResults#4094092%60) the comment says to use the continuity to get a contradiction,
I have been struggling to find it, can anyone help?

Comment: I just posted a comment there answering Chris Ewing’s request for more details. It’s really very straightforward, so I prefer not to write out the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r: X \to A$ be the retract, and suppose $x \in \overline{A}$ but $x \notin A$ (this is saying that $A$ is not closed).
As $x \neq r(x)$ and $X$ is Hausdorff we have open sets $U,V$ so that

$$x \in U, r(x) \in V, U \cap V = \emptyset$$

Then $r^{-1}[V]$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ because $r$ is continuous (and $r(x) \in V$ implies $x \in r^{-1}[V]$) and so the intersection $U \cap r^{-1}[V]$ *also* is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and because $x \in \overline{A}$ we have that $(U \cap r^{-1}[V]) \cap A \neq \emptyset$. Let $a$ be in that intersection then $a \in U$ by definition, and $a = r(a) \in V$ because $a \in r^{-1}[V]$ (and using that $r$ is the identity on $A$!), so $a \in U \cap V$ contradicting the disjointness... QED

Comment: Thank you so much, I really understand it now, it all makes sense

Comment: @GeorgeRevingston you’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

All neighbourhoods in this post will be open! Suppose $A$ is not closed and $x\in\text{cl}(A)\setminus A$, as suggested. Since we are dealing with a Hausdorff space, $x$ and $a:=r(x)$ will have disjoint neighbourhoods $U, V$, respectively. However, the retraction $r\colon X\to A$ is continuous, so there is some nbd $W$ of $x$ such that $rW \subseteq V$. Then $x\in U' := U\cap W$, $U'$ is open and $rU' \subseteq V$. Since $x$ is in the closure of $A$, we can conclude that $U'\cap A \neq\emptyset$, and thus $r(U'\cap A) = U'\cap A$. This is now where the contradiction arises. Firstly, we know that $U'\cap A = r(U' \cap A) \subseteq rU'$, so it will intersect $V$ non-vacuously (by the continuity of $r$). On the other hand, $(U'\cap A)\cap V \subseteq U\cap  V = \emptyset$. Only one of those can be true, but with the assumption that $A$ is not closed, they both are.